# is there any extension for product option's price(product variation's price) in opencart4?

Tags: opencart, product

I want to add a float price for the product option's price, but the latest version of opencart4 didn't provide this facility for the users. It took only integer value and neglect float ( 1.023 ) price or convert it into round about... If there is any extension related to it, just let me know.

I tried to find extensions, but for the latest version 4(opencart), I didn't get any result related to the current version. If you know any extensions, just let me know.

Comment: Have you tried to find in OC marketplace? Maybe this one: https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension/info&member_token=87ce97236ff5d8c583777617dcab49e4&extension_id=21780

Answer (score 0):

You can check the following extension
PRICE BY FORMULA + live price update+dependent options
you also can request additional features from the extension developers. This by far is the most flexible pricing addon for the new Opencart 4.

Answer (score 0):

Many experienced developers are against using Opencart 4 for production website. Opencart 3.0.3.8 is the best at the moment for production website.